# How to predefine message in FBDialog?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm integrating Facebook into my app, and I want FBDialog to be predefined with my text. So i've tried this parameters:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"Some message text", @"message",
nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But comment field is still empty, is it possible to prefill it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pre-fill the message and is against Facebook policy so your message input is ignored.